# How do I make text go in front of a picture?

Tags: html, tumblr

How can I put links and text over this?

[image]

Like this the light orange here?

[image]

Here is the link
pastebin . com /hcyyczXP

Comment: try opacity .. for orange or z-index

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a `<div>`, and in CSS give it a color. Then put text in it. Also, letting us see your code would help a lot.

Comment: Uh, maybe not your 1136 lines of code, just the ones relevant to the question. But my answer should still work for you. You can learn about divs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

Comment: it would do this http://imgur.com/TKFTDfq and when i would scroll down it would stay at its place

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following:

```
 <div class="image">
  <img src="image/orange.jpg" alt="" />
  <h2>This is my text</h2>
</div>


.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

That should work. But without any code from you, it's hard to make anything.

Comment: You added way to much code lol. All we really need is the block that needs help with and the css that goes with that block :)

Comment: Oops sorry about that, do you think you can still help me with it?

Comment: Copy over the parts that need help in your post and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Wait i think it would be this part of it. The word would be 'bars' 
pastebin. com /vVSWLJLD